# How do I know which C Standard am I using?

Tags: c

I am using Dev C++ for my C projects. I was asking few questions on Stackoverflow about my code and some answers suggests that I am using "old" function (in my case gets()) which is not supported anymore by C Standard. So my question is how do I know which C Standard am I using and on what it depends? If it is built in compiler ,what would be most practical compiler to use which is up to date?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this and it depends on what compiler you're using. Let's assume you're on linux and using gcc. Run:

```
gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null
```

It will print out all compiler defined macros. Look for `#define __STDC_VERSION__ 201112L`